# Using Imagick Composite to apply a "frame"

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Alright, I have a bit of a dilemma I have been struggling with.  I'm attempting to use ImageMagick to add a "frame", for lack of a better term, to a member profile picture.  I am setting the frame icon, and then fetching the member picture, but I am getting a "Failed to read the file" exception when I try and save the file.

Here is my code:

```
$overlapImage = new Imagick($current_dir . "/images/EmeraldPro.png");

// This is a local function written for me that returns the content directory and image name in one string.

$member_picture = $temp_account->get_ProfileImage($member, "140", "content");

$temp_member_picture = new Imagick($member_picture);

$temp_member_picture->compositeImage($overlapImage, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, 0, 0);

try{
    $temp_member_picture->writeImage($dir.$newFileName);
} catch (ImagickException $e) {
    print __LINE__."\n";
    print $e->getMessage();exit;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you ***really*** need to use ImageMagick or can you just add a CSS frame for the image on the HTML? (assuming this is a php-based web application, of course)

Comment: I would try something simple first with direct inputs and the images in the same folder. This would prove the Imagick code was working; then build on that.

Comment: Are you sure `"$dir.$newFileName"` is a valid path to a writable directory?

Comment: ochi - You have a dang good point.  Maybe I'll attempt to use CSS to do this.

Bonzo - Should ochi's solution not work, I'll certainly start there.

miken - Yes, I'm certain, I printed out and debugged to make sure.